# Seeking Guidance on Calculus Exercises and Solutions for Self-Study

Tags: calculus, reference-request, self-learning

*I am a second-year undergraduate student in biotechnology. I've previously taken a course in calculus, but I confess I didn't put my effort into studying it. As a result, I'm somewhat in the dark about most of the content.

However, as someone aspiring to continue as a researcher, I realize how inconvenient it could be not having a good understanding of calculus. Thus, I've decided to study it again on my own. Now that I am on vacation, it seems like the good time to dive back in.

As I look through the calculus textbook PDF, I see that it is packed with a massive number of exercises. Attempting to complete all of them seems quite overwhelming and impractical, given the limited time I have.*

(Here are the question)
**So, I'm seeking your advice: are there any key or essential exercises that you would recommend? Or perhaps some guidelines or strategies for choosing the more worth problems to tackle?**

Additionally, the textbook does not provide solutions, which is a bit inconvenient for self-study. If anyone could suggest effective methods or resources to obtain the solutions, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Welcome to the site! THis question has been asked about morbillion times on this site, have you tried going over the previous questions on this topic?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The majority of them are impractical, that's true. In your case, I would take all textbooks in your course and look at where they use calculus. What they typically do is create a model for a particular biological phenomena (say cancer spread modelling or a particular enzyme catalytic reaction), and then analyze this model using techniques of calculus. To the best of my knowledge, there is no "pattern" that tells you that xyz exercise is good and abc is not in an *applied* field, which is why your best guide is precisely those models and what calculations they involve.

Comment: In addition to what others have said, you may want to consider carefully reading [**A Mathematical Nature Walk**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0691152659) by John Anthony Adam (2009), paying special attention to the mathematical techniques and ideas, perhaps using these as a guide to what to study in other books (e.g. anti-differentiation by trig substitution -- not so much; precalculus topics, and differentials for approximations, and setting up definite integrals and simple ODEs -- much more so). The table of contents can be viewed [here](https://archive.org/details/mathematicalnatu0000adam).